# Query Sql Server able to delete the last row of the table

Tags: javascript, c#, sql

I would like to expose you my problem: practically, through an AJAX function I call a server-side function, which should execute a query. This query, based on the data provided, deletes the last row of the table where the data in question is present. In the server side function everything works except the query, which instead of deleting the last row, deletes all the rows. Can anyone tell me the exact query?

```
public static void Contr_Dati(string provin)
    {
        string queryString = "DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE (SELECT MAX (Province_Inserite) FROM Prov_inser) = @Prov";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["coso"].ConnectionString))
        {

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("Prov", provin);
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Of course it does: your query is like `DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE 1 = 1` (in that the result of the WHERE clause isn't contingent on the value in a given row). Your query states: if the result of `(SELECT MAX (Province_Inserite) FROM Prov_inser)` equals `@Prov` then delete all rows in `Prov_inser`. Do you just want `DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE Province_Inserite = @prov`?

Comment: I tried DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE Province_Inserite = @Prov and it works, it deletes all the data in the table that is the same as what I insert. What I am looking for is something more accurate, I would like the last data entered to be deleted based on what I entered in input. For example I enter "Hello", I would like the last line where "Hello" was entered to be deleted. I hope I have been clearer.

Comment: If Province_Inserite is the row id, then you might want something like `DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE Province_Inserite = (SELECT MAX(Province_Inserite) FROM Prov_inser WHERE  /*someconditionhere*/)`. I'm not really sure what these columns represent, or what @prov is, so I can't really help more than that. Perhaps you could edit your question.

Comment: @prov is an input that I type from the keyboard in a textarea.
I may not have formulated the question well, anyway thank you so much for the suggestions, very kind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `@Prov` is the Max(key) of the table, your query

```
DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE (SELECT MAX (Province_Inserite) FROM Prov_inser) = @Prov
```

is equal to

```
DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE 1 = 1
```

which will delete all rows in the table

===================================================================

So you have to change it to

```
DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE Province_Inserite = @Prov
```

or without parameter

```
DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE Province_Inserite = (SELECT MAX(Province_Inserite) FROM Prov_inser)
```

If `@Prov` isn't a key, you have to add a key or a timestamp audit field (i.g. Created_Time) to identify the last inserted row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that comes closest to the problem is: 'DELETE FROM Prov_inser WHERE Province_Inserite = Prov'. However @prov is not a key, but rather an input parameter. Prov_Inser is the name of the table and Province_Inserite is not the key.